# Oracle Apex change the autocomplete typing color

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Is it possible to change the color of the letters we type in the autocomplete page item?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes; navigate to **Custom attributes** item's property and put something like that into it:

```
style="color:red"
```

(it'll paint letters *red*).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Littlefoot. I added a photo to show you exactly where I want to change the color

Comment: Aha. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome; sorry for not being able to help any better.